# Tkinter strange on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have made a short clock program (from a lesson). On linux and Windows, it all displays as it should like this:
[image: linux or windows view]

Under OSX is looks like this with the grey box around the text:
[image: OSX - same code]

Can anyone tell me whats going on?
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import time
import datetime

def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()

def clock_time():
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    txt.set(time)
    root.after(1000,clock_time)

root = Tk()
root.title('PyClock')
root.attributes("-fullscreen",False)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x",quit)
root.after(1000,clock_time)

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=120, weight='bold')
txt = StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground='white', background='black')
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ttk on MacOS strives to be as native as possible.
As such, many of the backgrounds and colors for Ttk widgets cannot be configured.

A standard label can be used instead of the ttk.Label, and it will allow
the background to be configured.

Comment: As a beginner, I am not sure what you mean without an example. I fixed it though by just changing the background color to the same gray as the box the text is in and then making the font black. I am happy with that.

Comment: You might be able to select a different theme that lets the foreground and background be configured.